# Next js Strapi integration not displaying data

Tags: axios, next.js, strapi

I am trying to build a simple task website to get familiar with full stack development. I am using Next js and Strapi. I have tried all I can think of, but the data from the server just will not display on the frontend. It seems to me that the page loads too soon, before the data has been loaded in. However, I am not a full stack dev and am therefore not sure.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const Tasks = ({ tasks }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {tasks && tasks.map(task => (
        <li key={task.id}>{task.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/tasks');
  const data = await res.data;

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  } else {
    console.log(data)
  }

  return {
    props: { tasks: data },
  };
};

export default Tasks;
```

Comment: How is this not working? What do you see happen vs what do you expect to see?

Comment: So to clarify: I am trying to render a list of task names fetched from the backend. What I instead get is a blank page with only a black dot on it, signifying an empty unordered list.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fetch task data at build time?

Comment: `res.data` is not a promise, you don't need to `await` for it when assigning `const data = await res.data;`.

Comment: Also, do you get the expected response data from the API call in `getStaticProps`?

Comment: How else would I fetch it if not at build time, like I am now? How can I then get it to update correctly?

Comment: I removed the await from that call, but it made no difference. I am not sure what you mean by your second question, but if you are talking about the console log, then yes that gives a correct array

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to call the api from the pages files in the pages folder. I don't know why this is but that's how it works.